# Tkinter multiprocessing problem : !xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm having a problem using Tkinter.

What I'm trying to do is, to **start()** a **multiprocessing.Process()** when I press a button.
However, I get the !xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost problem whenever I click the button.
Here's the code that I'm using :

```
def execute_tests_multiprocess(root):
    my_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    multi_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=execute_tests, args=(root, my_queue,))
    multi_proc.start()
```